# Why am I getting huge slowdown when parallelising with OpenMP and using static scheduling?

Tags: c, performance, openmp

I'm working to parallelise a disease spread model in c using OpenMP but am only seeing massive (order of magnitude) slowdown. I'll point out at the outset that I am a complete novice with both OpenMP and c.

The code loops over every point in the simulation and checks its status (susceptible, infected, recovered) and for each status, follows an algorithm to determine its status at the next time step.

I'll give the loop for infected points for illustrative purposes. `Lpoints` is a list of indices for points in the simulation, `Nneigh` gives the number of neighbours each point has and `Lneigh` gives the indices of these neighbours.

```
for (ipoint=0;ipoint<Nland;ipoint++) { //loop over all points
      if (Lpoints_old[ipoint]==I) { //act on infected points

        /* Probability Prec of infected population recovering */
        xi = genrand();
        if (xi<Pvac) { /* This point recovers (I->R) */

          Lpoints[ipoint] = R;
          /* printf("Point %d gained immunity\n",ipoint); */  
        }
        else { 
          /* Probability of being blockaded by neighbours */
          nsn = 0;
          for (in=0;in<Nneigh[ipoint];in++) { /*count susceptible neighbours (nsn)*/
                  //if (npoint<0) printf("Bad npoint 1: %d in=%d\n",ipoint,in); 
                  //fflush(stdout);
            npoint = Lneigh[ipoint][in];
            if (Lpoints_old[npoint]==S) nsn++;
          }
          Prob = (double)nsn*Pblo;
          xi = genrand();
          if (xi<Prob) { /* The population point is blockaded (I->R)*/
            
            Lpoints[ipoint] = R;
          }
          else { /* Still infected */
            
            Lpoints[ipoint] = I;
          }
        } /*else*/
      } /*infected*/
    } /*for*/
```

I tried to parallelise by adding `#pragma omp parallel for default(shared) private(ipoint,xi,in,npoint,nsn,Prob)` before the for loop. (I tried using `default(none)` as is generally recommended but it wouldn't compile.) On the small grid I am using to test the original series code runs in about 5 seconds and the OpenMP version runs in around 50.

I have searched for ages online and every similar problem seems to be the result of false cache sharing and has been solved by using static scheduling with a chunk size divisible by 8. I tried varying the chunk size to no effect whatsoever, only getting the timings to the original order when the chunk size surpassed the size of the problem (i.e. back to linearly carrying out on one thread.)
[image: These results are shown here. There are 100,000 simulation points in the test data so approximately original performance is restored here.]

Slowdown doesn't seem any better when the problem is more appropriately scaled as far as I can tell either. I have no idea why this isn't working and what's going wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Didn't dig in any deeper, so just view hints: Threads do not come for free, they have quite some overhead (allocating a stack, initialising thread scheduling, ...). For small problems to solve this overhead can be larger than the problem itself, then you even see a performance loss. You won't gain any performance either if you have more threads than CPU cores (unless competing with other processes for ressources if these are equally distributed over all threads in the system). And some problems are poorly parallelisable by their nature already.

Comment: Is this `genrand()` function thread-safe?

Comment: How do you measure runtime? Always define your variables in their minimum required scope and yes, use `default(none)` clause, so you have to explicitly set the sharing attributes. If you get an error you have forgot to define the sharing attribute of a variable.

Comment: How big is `NLand`? 5s seems to be too much for this code (or do you have an outer loop as well?). Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @Laci There is indeed probably an external loop on time steps

Comment: @Shawn `genrand()` is maybe not thread-safe, or it is thread-safe but with locks that can explain a part of the slowdowns

Comment: Instead of tinkering with private/shared, make all your loop variables defined in the loop header. You probably have something that is executed redundantly on each thread, Also as other people point out: use a threadsafe random number generator. C++ has a good one.

Comment: @Laci Nland is the quantity which is approximately 100,000 so you are right, the process described in the original question is repeated each time step inside a larger while loop which will continue until there are either no infected or no susceptible people left. This is why I only gave one of the for loops. I'm not sure I could reduce the entire problem without copying it entirely (at my current ability). Regarding ```default(none)```, I thought I covered everything necessary and the error message was citing the ```omp``` part of the ```pragma```. I thought this was weird?

Comment: @Aconcagua I did wonder about this but my testing with the chunk size convinced me otherwise. I thought the fact that I could get so close to the original performance by declaring all the threads and only using one of them meant that this probably wasn't too important. Or is it the case that OpenMP will see that it has 100,000 tasks and a chunk size of 100,000 and only initialise one thread?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to do so, don't play with the chunk size and leave it by default. The most obvious suspect in your problem is `genrand()`

Comment: Please edit your post and show us your `genrand()` function. You only showed us the "loop for infected points for illustrative purposes", but I guess you also considered the spread of the disease in another loop as well. Did you also parallelize that loop? How do you copy `Lpoints` to `Lpoints_old`? Probably the best idea is if you show us all of your code in codereview.stackexchange.com. You will definitely receive many ideas on how to make it faster. Most probably its performance can be increased even without using parallelization.

Comment: @OliverBunting At this point I cannot tell how OpenMP actually works under the hoods. Just declaring the threads, though, doesn't necessarily mean that the underlying OS thread is created right at the same moment...